# variables no definidas

Tags: php, mysqli

Cuando me logueo con un usuario que no es 'admin' debe aparecerme, un formulario, para actualizar el gasto_total. Pues cuando  pongo el dato, y le doy al submit, me salen dos errores

Notice: Undefined index: usuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\examen\validar_cliente.php on line 5
Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\examen\validar_cliente.php on line 6

por que me salen estos dos errores? no entiendo, a que viene que me salga el usuario y contraseña.

Este es el repositorio https://github.com/blugnomeXD/examen

`````
<?php

    include('biblioteca.php');

    $usuario =$_POST['usuario'];
    $password =$_POST['password'];

    $consulta ="SELECT usuario,pass FROM clientes WHERE usuario ='$usuario' AND pass ='$password'";
    $allusers = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
    $showUser ="SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE usuario ='$usuario' AND pass ='$password'";

    $rest_consulta =mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($rest_consulta,MYSQLI_ASSOC);


    //Modificar
    if($fila==true){
        if($usuario=='admin'){
            echo "<h1>Tus datos de cuenta</h1>";
            $show_users =mysqli_query($conexion,$allusers);
            while($fila_registro = mysqli_fetch_array($show_users,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

             echo '<table> ';
             echo '<tr>';        
                   echo  '<th>'. $fila_registro['usuario'] . '</th>' ;
                   echo  '<th>'. $fila_registro['pass'] . '</th>' ;
                   echo  '<th>'. $fila_registro['nombre'] . '</th>' ;
                   echo  '<th>'. $fila_registro['apellido1'] . '</th>' ;
                   echo  '<th>'. $fila_registro['apellido2'] . '</th>' ;
                   echo  '<th>'. $fila_registro['telefono'] . '</th>' ;
                   echo  '<th>'. $fila_registro['total_gastado'] . '</th>' ;
             echo '<tr>';
             echo '</table>';
           } 

        }else{

            $show_user =mysqli_query($conexion,$showUser);
            while($fila_registro = mysqli_fetch_array($show_user,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                echo "<h1>Tus datos de cuenta</h1>";
             echo '<table> ';
             echo '<tr>';        
                   echo  '<th>'. $fila_registro['usuario'] . '</th>' ;
                   echo  '<th>'. $fila_registro['pass'] . '</th>' ;
                   echo  '<th>'. $fila_registro['nombre'] . '</th>' ;
                   echo  '<th>'. $fila_registro['apellido1'] . '</th>' ;
                   echo  '<th>'. $fila_registro['apellido2'] . '</th>' ;
                   echo  '<th>'. $fila_registro['telefono'] . '</th>' ;
                   echo  '<th>'. $fila_registro['total_gastado'] . '</th>' ;
             echo '<tr>';
             echo '</table>';
           }    

        echo "<hr>";
        echo "<form method='POST' action='validar_cliente.php'>
            <label for='dinero'>Dinero:</label><input type='text' name='dinero'>
              <input type='submit' value='Actualizar'> </form>";  
        }
    }
    /*
    if($fila<=0){

        //modificar
        echo 'modificar';
    }*/
    mysqli_close($conexion);
?>

---

El formulario donde ingreso la información del usuario es el siguiente



<form action="validar_cliente.php" method="POST">
    <label for="usuario">Usuario: </label><input type="text" name="usuario"> <br>
    <label for="password">Contraseña: </label><input type="text" name="password"> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Ingresar">
</form>




Ahi hay algún error? 

Por que por ejemplo, cuando voy a ingresar un login, funciona bien me sale todo como yo quiero.

Hay otra cosa que me pasa, y es en este formulario que lo hago atraves de PHP, me salta el error  Notice: Undefined variable: dinero in C:\xampp\htdocs\examen\validar_cliente.php on line 75
Por qué sale como que no lo tengo definido, si lo  he puesto en el formulario?

````

 echo "<form name='formulario' method='post' action='validar_cliente.php'>
         Dinero <input type='text' name='dinero' > 
        <input type='submit'></form>";
        $dinero=$_POST['dinero'];

        $update = "UPDATE clientes SET total_gastado = total_gastado+($dinero) WHERE usuario ='$usuario' AND pass='$password'";
`````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Añade este código antes del `include`:

```
if(!isset($_POST['usuario'])){
    echo '
        <form method="post">
        <input name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario"/>
        <input name="password" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
        <button>Enviar</button>
        </form>
    ';
    exit();
}
```

El error que comentas te aparece porque, probablemente, no estarás enviando correctamente los datos desde el formulario que te pide las credenciales y estás haciendo uso de unas variables que aún no se han creado. Prueba así, y me comentas.

Simplemente compruebo que la variable haya sido inicializada y, de lo contrario, muestro el formulario que la generará cuando la web se llame a sí misma. Por defecto el atributo `action` del `form` está dirigido al mismo script de php.

Para que podamos ayudarte, recuerda que es mejor que selecciones los fragmentos de código que no funcionan como esperas. Así recibirás respuesta mucho antes. Ten en cuenta que hay muchas cosas en tu código que no podemos probar, como biblioteca.php o la base de datos.

*Advertencia*: Presta mucha atención a las vulnerabilidades por inyección de código. En sucesivas versiones, deberías al menos parametrizar las consultas.

Answer (score 2):

(Para completar la respuesta de @david JP)

El problema que tienes en tu código es que, una vez que aparece el formulario de gasto_total, pones el valor y envias, resulta que estas enviando ese post (solamente el campo dinero) al MISMO PHP. En tu caso, lo primero que haces es validar el user/pass, y como este ultimo formulario SOLO envia el campo dinero, aparece el error "undefined index" en la variable $_POST.

Para solucionarlo, tienes varias opciones. La solución de @david JP es correcta. (añadir una comprobación y poner un exit)

Otra solución seria que enviaras el formulario (cambiar el action="validar_cliente.php") a otro archivo php que realmente gestionara el tema de los gastos. Por ejemplo, podrías hacer un "validar_gastos.php" que hiciera el update correspondiente.

Si te das cuenta, estas mezclando lógica de validar el usuario (eso debería hacerlo un archivo en concreto) y lógica de gastos (que serán cosa de contabilidad, no relacionada con la lógica de validar user). Debes tener cuidado de esas cosas (aparte que estas mezclando lógica de proceso con presentación. Te recomiendo que revises MVC y algún framework, para que veas como se van solucionando estos temas.

Comment: He probado lo que me has comentado, lo que hice fue crear un include para  poder recoger las dos variables usuario, y  password, para asi hacer el update, pero cuando le doy a enviar, me salta directamente a ' no estoy registrado'.